# JMS MDB or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor for asynchronous tasks

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, ejb, jms, message-driven-bean

I've been using JMS `Message Driven Bean` for a while and it is working great for the asynchronous tasks. I know that there is many ways to handle the asynchronous processes, but I am just curious what are the benefits over using JMS `Message Driven Bean` and `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`?

For example I have a web service which handles some tasks asynchronously. So I see two main differences. If I would be using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` I don't need application server, I could use a servlet container for e.g. Tomcat, because I am not using any EJB stuff, for MDB I need an application server, for e.g. Glassfish. But in terms of handling the actual asynchronous process, what are the advantages over each `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and `MDB`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) is used to schedule tasks, the abstraction best corresponding to MDB is [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). But back to your question.

MDB is more heavyweight, API is much more complex and in principle it was actually designed for transferring data, not logic. On the other hand `ExecutorService` is a thin layer on top of actual thread pool. So if you need performance, low latency and small overhead, go for ordinary thread pool.

The only reason for MDB and JMS is when you need durability and transaction support. That of course introduces even bigger overhead as each message needs to be persisted. But you won't loose any tasks that are queued or even in the middle of processing are not lost due to crash.